# Mwan3 replacement on debian

Tags: debian, networking, openwrt

I have just moved from openwrt to debian 11 on my x86 system for network management because i need some debian's stuffs. I cannot find out a replacement for mwan3 in load balancing my pppoes. Can someone help?

Comment: I don't think there's a port of mwan3 to debian. But there's possibly multiple alternatives, depending on how complicated your requirements are. Suspecting those is rather classical, multi ISP, small to medium LAN, https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ppp-gatekeeper maybe?

Comment: If the setup is not complex, it's absolutely not unreasonable to just run openwrt in a VM on your x86_64 and let it handle the necessary network interfaces, either. There's a whole lot of solutions for networking you can build on debian, from tiny destination or source based solutions that you can just script with iproute to complete SDNs...

Comment: My hardware is not so powerful. In VM, the speed is halved down. I will look through ppp-gatekeeper. Thanks

Comment: Hm, any x86_64 processor of the last decade should do virtualization well enough for speed to not be significantly reduced